# Logitech G733 working for recording (input) but not to listen (output)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, logitech

When I go to volume management, I can change my input device to my headphone (logitech g733) but I can't select it as output device. Any trick to make it work?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with pulseaudio but I also tried on a livecd of Ubuntu 21.04 with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I have the G733 and they worked out of the box with pop_os 21.10, with a trick: they are recognized as two outputs at the same time: Analog and Digital. So far, Digital works best for me, even the volume rocker works.
[See this screenshot of Logitech G733 showing as analog AND digital Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Xjq.png)

The trick for me to be able to select the input and output is the "Sound Input & Output Device Chooser" gnome extension available here:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/

Hope this helps!